# Click event for multiple collapsible d3 tree in a single page

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, tree

I have implement multiple collapsible tree in a page using http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083

But I am facing a problem with the click event. When I click a node it does not collapse or expand. The collapsible event works only for the last tree (Issues tree) as it the last svg loaded. (Example : http://tinypic.com/r/2zzqcn5/8)

How to get the click event to work for all the tree? Will using iframe for each graph solve this problem? if so how to do it?

Thanks.

**JSON data for each function call of collapse_graph(type):**

**1st Iteration: type = Artifacts**

```
{"name":"artifacts","children":[
    {"name":"weights","children":[]},
    {"name":"sampling compartment","children":[]},
    {"name":"depth guage","children":[
       {"name":"Decomp8","children":[
          {"name":"Pressure gauge","children":[]}]},
          {"name":"Decomp9","children":[
              {"name":"a sensor that determines the depth","children":[]}
       ]}
    ]}
]}
```

**2nd Iteration: type = Behaviour**

```
{"name":"behaviors","children":[
    {"name":"Hydrostatic pressure","children":[
        {"name":"Decomp6","children":[
            {"name":"Ro","children":[]},
            {"name":"h","children":[]},
            {"name":"g","children":[]}
        ]}
    ]}
]}
```

**3rd Iteration: type = Issue**

```
{"name":"issues","children":[
    {"name":"withstanding pressure in depth","children":[]}
]}
```

**Code:**

```
/* Collapsible Tree Global variables */
var tree, diagonal, svg;
var inc = 0, duration = 750, root;


$('#tabs').append("<h2>Artifacts</h2>");
collapse_graph('artifact');            
$('#tabs').append("<h2>Behaviors</h2>");            
collapse_graph('behavior');            
$('#tabs').append("<h2>Issues</h2>");          
collapse_graph('issue');


function collapse(d) {
    if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
    d._children.forEach(collapse);
    d.children = null;
    }
}

function collapse_graph(type){

var data = {};
    //data['name'] = type + "s";
    //data['children'] = getChildrenEntities(type);

    if(type == 'artifact') {
    data = JSON.parse('{"name":"artifacts","children":[{"name":"weights","children":[]},{"name":"sampling compartment","children":[]},{"name":"depth guage","children":[{"name":"Decomp8","children":[{"name":"Pressure gauge","children":[]}]},{"name":"Decomp9","children":[{"name":"a sensor that determines the depth","children":[]}]}]}]}');
    }

    if (type == 'behavior') {
    data = JSON.parse('{"name":"behaviors","children":[{"name":"Hydrostatic pressure","children":[{"name":"Decomp6","children":[{"name":"Ro","children":[]},{"name":"h","children":[]},{"name":"g","children":[]}]}]}]}');
    }

    if (type == 'issue') {
    data = JSON.parse('{"name":"issues","children":[{"name":"withstanding pressure in depth","children":[]}]}');
    }

    // d3 business.
    var width = 800;
    var height = 500;

tree = d3.layout.tree().size([height, width]);

diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal().projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });

svg = d3.select("#tabs").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(100,0)");

  root = data;
  root.x0 = height / 2;
  root.y0 = 0;

  root.children.forEach(collapse);
  update(root);

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "800px");
}

function update(source) {

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
  links = tree.links(nodes);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 180; });

  // Update the nodes…
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
  .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++inc); });

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 +       ")"; })
  .on("click", click);

  nodeEnter.append("circle")
  .attr("r", 1e-6)
  .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

  nodeEnter.append("text")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10; })
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
  .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
  .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
  .duration(duration)
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });

  nodeUpdate.select("circle")
  .attr("r", 4.5)
  .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

  nodeUpdate.select("text")
  .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
  .duration(duration)
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
  .remove();

  nodeExit.select("circle")
  .attr("r", 1e-6);

  nodeExit.select("text")
  .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Update the links…
  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
  .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
  .attr("class", "link")
  .attr("d", function(d) {
    var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
    return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
  });

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
  .duration(duration)
  .attr("d", diagonal);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
  .duration(duration)
  .attr("d", function(d) {
    var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
    return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
  })
  .remove();

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
  d.x0 = d.x;
  d.y0 = d.y;
  });
  inc = 0;
}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } 
  else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }

  update(d);
}
```

Comment: Are the nodes in all 3 trees hooked up to the same listener (i.e. `click` function)?

Comment: Hi @FernOfTheAndes !!

Yes. It call the same function to create all the graph.

Comment: Not seeing your code, I suspect you problem might be that you are calling the same handler for all trees which itself is calling the same update function...

Comment: @FernOfTheAndes...i have attached the code for your reference. how do i modify it to work for all the trees??Thanks

Comment: A piece of the code is missing: `getChildrenEntities()` function. Please add that and any other part that might be missing.

Comment: @FernOfTheAndes
I have added json data to the post. Can you please convert it into array and initial to "var data = {}" ?

Otherwise i have to share my entire code which uses other libraries to fetch json data.

Thanks!

Comment: Besides `getChildrenEntities()` missing, `Entities` are missing as well. It is hard to re-construct your situation as is. I am not sure how to help you.

Comment: @FernOfTheAndes
I have modified the code removing unwanted variables and codes. Please take a look at it. Thanks

Comment: From my end, I don't have good news. Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x2qJz/). As you can see, I was able to call the separate click functions (although use of `eval` is definitely not recommended) and pass the right nodes. **But it is not that simple.** The different selections (enter, update, exit) plus class attributes are all based on nodes/links of the last graph built. IMHO, your best bet is to factor this code out into a re-usable component. Otherwise, the code will be complex and difficult to maintain.

Comment: @FernOfTheAndes
Appreciate your help. If you get some idea let me know and Thanks for trying out.

Comment: Finally I found a way to sort out this issue. Please find the code in the below jsfiddle link. **Demo**: jsfiddle.net/x2qJz/4/ Thanks

Comment: Excellent! I am impressed by the simplicity of the solution. Congratulations. Please post this solution...it is totally acceptable to post an answer to one's own question. This solution by-passed the need to turn the chart into a re-usable component...however, one final note from me would be for you to explore the component alternative...it is the more scalable solution.

Comment: Thanks @FernOfTheAndes. Will look into your suggestion as well.

Answer (score 2):

Solution is storing each data, svg in an array and in click event call the function with the corresponding tree data.

**Here is the working code:**

```
/* Collapsible Tree Global variables */
var tree, diagonal, svg = [];
var inc = 0, duration = 750, root = [];


$('#tabs').append("<h2>Artifacts</h2>");
collapse_graph('artifact');            
$('#tabs').append("<h2>Behaviors</h2>");            
collapse_graph('behavior');            
$('#tabs').append("<h2>Issues</h2>");          
collapse_graph('issue');

function collapse_graph(type){

var data = {};
//data['name'] = type + "s";
//data['children'] = getChildrenEntities(type);

if(type == 'artifact') {
data = JSON.parse('{"name":"artifacts","children":[{"name":"weights","children":[]},{"name":"sampling compartment","children":[]},{"name":"depth guage","children":[{"name":"Decomp8","children":[{"name":"Pressure gauge","children":[]}]},{"name":"Decomp9","children":[{"name":"a sensor that determines the depth","children":[]}]}]}]}');
}

if (type == 'behavior') {
data = JSON.parse('{"name":"behaviors","children":[{"name":"Hydrostatic pressure","children":[{"name":"Decomp6","children":[{"name":"Ro","children":[]},{"name":"h","children":[]},{"name":"g","children":[]}]}]}]}');
}

if (type == 'issue') {
data = JSON.parse('{"name":"issues","children":[{"name":"withstanding pressure in depth","children":[]}]}');
}

// d3 business.
var width = 800;
var height = 500;

tree = d3.layout.tree().size([height, width]);

diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal().projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });

svg[type] = d3.select("#tabs").append("svg")
    .attr("type", type)
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(100,0)");

root[type] = data;
  root[type].x0 = height / 2;
  root[type].y0 = 0;

  //root.children.forEach(collapse);
  update(root[type], type);

  //d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "800px");
}

function update(source,type) {

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root[type]).reverse(),
  links = tree.links(nodes);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 180; });

  // Update the nodes…
  var node = svg[type].selectAll("g.node")
  .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++inc); });

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 +")"; }).on('click', click);

  nodeEnter.append("circle")
  .attr("r", 1e-6)
  .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

  nodeEnter.append("text")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10; })
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
  .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
  .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
  .duration(duration)
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });

  nodeUpdate.select("circle")
  .attr("r", 4.5)
  .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

  nodeUpdate.select("text")
  .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
  .duration(duration)
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
  .remove();

  nodeExit.select("circle")
  .attr("r", 1e-6);

  nodeExit.select("text")
  .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Update the links…
  var link = svg[type].selectAll("path.link")
  .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
  .attr("class", "link")
  .attr("d", function(d) {
    var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
    return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
  });

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
  .duration(duration)
  .attr("d", diagonal);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
  .duration(duration)
  .attr("d", function(d) {
    var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
    return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
  })
  .remove();

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });
  inc = 0;
}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } 
  else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  var type = $(this).parents('svg').attr('type');
  update(d, type);
}
```